# 'Items in a bucket' optimizaiton problem?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Sorry for question's silly tittle. I don't quite know how to name my problem, that's why I'm here.

[image: Example Data]

Imagine you wish do add the collumns of you data ('1','2','3'...'30k' etc.) in such a way as to obtain the numbers in the Goal column.

You don't have to combine all the columns, combine only as many as necessary for you to obtain the column 'Goal'. In fact, my objective is to know which columns lead me to the column Goal. I may have to combine 2, 3, 4, 30k columns, doesn't matter as long as I find the 'shortest' solution possible, namely using as few collumns as possible.

My analogy to this problem would be something like puttings items in a blender until I reach the desired outcome. The order in which I add the collumns doesn't matter.

I mean to minimize the mean abstolute error (MAE) between the combination of columns and the Goal.

I have been reading about integer programming, but I don't quite know where exactly I should go to. Could anybody point me to which class of algorithms I can use to approach this type of problem?

Comment: is it always the case that the  Goal column can be exactly achieved (matched)? What do you want to do if it can''t? You would have to define a measure of closeness e.g.,  some norm of deviation from goal), and trade it off somehow vs. the number of columns used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does your data have exactly 4 rows as shown in your example table above? Or do you see yourself needing to have a solution that can handle inputs with many rows?